# Java program takes input twice

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

So below is my code. I'm trying to use the Scanner class to read an input from the console, and then print out each token on a separate line. But there's a small problem where the user has to input twice. An example of what happens is given below the code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringSort {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a string: ");

        String str = scanner.nextLine();

        int i = 0;
        while (i< str.length()) {
            i++;
            System.out.println("" + scanner.next());
        }
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Example:

```
Enter a string: 
what is love
what is love
what
is
love
```

Comment: what do you think `+ scanner.next());` does?

Comment: Please fix your indentation and clarify your question, what did you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more efficient implementation of the above code would be as follows:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(sc.next());
    }
```

This would avoid use of extra space as done by [@ScaryWombat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2310289/scary-wombat)

Answer (score 2):

To do what you want *use the Scanner class to read an input from the console, and then print out each token on a separate line* you can use the `String::split` method

```
String str = scanner.nextLine();
String [] arr = str.split (" ");
for (String x : arr) {
    System.out.println (x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner` should be propertly closed:

```
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(sc.next());
    }
}
```